# Citation in a table-note does not make footnote

Tags: citing, footnotes, tablenotes

So I am a bloody beginner with Latex and run into a very specific problem.
I have to cite with footnotes and copied some solution from here and now I can merrily cite with \autocite and my footnote appears.

I use to create my footnotes if my understanding is correct.

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
```

Now here is the catch, I also do need to cite a small table and I am required to declare it as a citation, but if I use the note the footnote is missing.
Thanks for your help and if more information is needed I'll provide it.

[image: Missing 6 in footnotes]

```
\begin{table}
\caption{An overview  for the possible combinations in the design of an intermediary }\label{tab-inter}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X}
{} & \textbf{Voluntarily} &  \textbf{Mandatory} \\
\hline
{\textbf{Decentralized Storage}} & {Voluntarily Data-Cache} &  {Mandatory Data-Cache} \\
\hline
{\textbf{Centralized Storage}} & {Voluntarily Data-Host} &  {Mandatory Data-Host} \\
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item \textbf{Note}: Own illustration of the graphic p.8 \autocite{Datentreuhand}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution

```
\begin{table}
\caption{An overview  for the possible combinations in the design of an intermediary }\label{tab-inter}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X}
{} & \textbf{Voluntarily} &  \textbf{Mandatory} \\
\hline
{\textbf{Decentralized Storage}} & {Voluntarily Data-Cache} &  {Mandatory Data-Cache} \\
\hline
{\textbf{Centralized Storage}} & {Voluntarily Data-Host} &  {Mandatory Data-Host} \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item \textbf{Note}: Own illustration of the graphic (p.8) \footnotemark
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\footcitetext{Datentreuhand}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!